# Problem while Making a Call and SMS in same Process on Windows Phone 7 

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a application for Windows Phone 7 in which on a button click I need to first send some text messages and then make a call. But as both process are user dependent so I am not getting how should I make it such a way that unless user first finishes the sending messages my app should not initiate call. Because unless I do so it will give thread abort exception.

Thanks;
nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done in reverse way. First make a call and then when user comes back after tombstoning send an Email...but flag manipulation need to be saved in isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

With the current SDK there is no way to know if the SMS was actually sent. It could also have been changed by the user before being sent!

Lots of people have asked for this functionality (or similar but for other tasks). Let's hope it comes in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do it in parallel, because WP7 isn't really multitask.
Do you really need to do it in parallel?
Search for the events deactivated and activated. They are in App.cs.
After you make a call, and back to the program, the activated event will detect it, so you can add code there to send SMS.